# Rescue mode with grub and chroot /mnt/sysimage after a VMWare conversion

Tags: fedora, grub

EDIT:  After some more snooping I saw this:

https://virtualkryptonite.blogspot.com/2017/07/vmware-converter-p2v-partition-number.html
(not sure what VG means in the post) but this is essentially what problems I had and what I need to do.  I believe I have a ISO I can use to create a minimal install but then I get lost on steps 4 and 5).
What is VG, and how do I mount the disk from the cloned yet not finished VM) to the new minimal install one...

I converted an old physical machine to VMWare and it failed at 97% with an error because something to do with raid, though given this KB Article:

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Converter-Standalone-Discussions/FAILED-An-error-occurred-during-the-conversion-Partition-number/td-p/454977

The conversion mostly should have the data there and all I have to do is setup grub.  Having never done this I tried to tell the VM to boot into a rescue cd I found from:

https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/4/i386/iso/

Which is an old rescue cd I believe for this old fedora machine I am trying to convert.

I can have the VM boot into this rescue cd where I have to answer several question, it tries to mount automatically the linux install to /mnt/sysimage but never finds it and gives me a prompt.

In the prompt, I can see that the machine sees my linux os drive as sda1, i.e. if I type:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sysimage
```

It looks like my OS is there is in /mnt/sysimage

I try to do a

```
grub-install /dev/sda1
```

/sbin/grub is not found, then aha from this link:

Even though I can type grub and go into the grub prompt.

So maybe I have to do more in this grub prompt to make sure the /dev/sda1 can be the boot drive or what but grub from the prompt I am not sure what to do (apparently you can type `ls` from a grub prompt but this one just gives an unrecognized command, it is GNU GRBU 0.95

So not sure where to go from here?

I did see this post here:

[GRUB does not load OS, displays grub> prompt](https://serverfault.com/questions/618373/grub-does-not-load-os-displays-grub-prompt)

but following that didn't get far as they say from grub prompt to type linux and I get Unrecognized command each time I try that?